# How can I move data in one column into multiple columns based on special character

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a simple Excel sheet with data in one column. How can I create columns based off the special character?

```
Special Char
row1
row2
row3
row4
row5
Special Char
row1
row2
row3
row4
Special Char
row1
row2
row3
row4
Special Char
row1
row2
```

Want it to look like this

```
Special Char   Special Char   Special Char   Special Char
row1           row1           row1           row1
row2           row2           row2           row2
row3           row3           row3           
row4           row4           row4           
row5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming there is no **`Excel Constraints`** as per the tags posted then the following formula should work:*

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, SCAN(0,A1:A19,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="Special Char",x+1,x))),
     IFERROR(DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(a),LAMBDA(x,y,HSTACK(x,FILTER(A1:A19,y=a)))),,1),""))
```

---

**Explanations:**

- First we are creating an array based on special characters to return a sequence like 1,2,3 etc for every change in special characters. So for the array returns like 1,1,1,1 and when it finds another special character it changes to 2 like wise 3 and so and so forth.

[image]

---

- Next, we are using the <kbd>REDUCE()</kbd> function, which iterates through the unique values of the array returned from <kbd>SCAN()</kbd>

[image]

---

- For each unique value it uses the <kbd>FILTER()</kbd> function to filter the range returned using <kbd>SCAN()</kbd> and returns the output range from `A1:A19` vertically and stacked horizontally using the <kbd>HSTACK()</kbd> as per the given output.

[image]

---

- To remove the first column and remove the errors, we are using <kbd>DROP()</kbd> and <kbd>IFERROR()</kbd> Function

[image]

---

[image]

---

Comment: Very nice! Can you add a small blurb to help me understand what's going on.

Comment: @Rod Sir, sure thing, i will update.

Comment: I have a follow up post if you don't mind taking a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77360147/139698

Comment: Yes I am writing on that